# theano grad computation "illegally returned an integer-valued variable."

Tags: neural-network, theano

I am computing a tensor which is a complex number, but then I take its magnitude and cast it as `float32`:

```
x = theano.tensor.abs_(cum).astype(theano.config.floatX)
```

When I am trying to compute a cost function, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Elemwise{abs_,no_inplace}.grad  (Input index 0, dtype complex128)
```

I have no idea why this is happening.Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently as long as any complex number computation is done in Theano, this problem arises, doesn't matter if the absolute value is being sent to the gradient computation. I fixed it by bypassing any complex number computation.

Comment: Could you share more details on how exactly you bypassed it?